# Quantum Full Adder

Tags: circuits, quantum-computing

I've been working on Quantum Circuits for a 1.5 months. And firstly i've created Full Adder in Quantum Circuit. And first times i was creating Full Adder with too Qubits. But last week i created another circuit like that:

[image]

And code here:

```
def LessQubitAdder(X, Y):
    xBin, yBin = DecimalToBinary(X), DecimalToBinary(Y)
    x, y = AddZero(xBin, yBin)

    CircuitLenght = len(x)
    QubitCount = 2 + CircuitLenght
    BitCount = CircuitLenght + 1
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(QubitCount, BitCount)
    j = 0
    for i in range(CircuitLenght):
        circuit.x(0) if x[i] == '1' else circuit.reset(0)
        circuit.x(1) if y[i] == '1' else circuit.reset(1)

        if i == 0:
            circuit.ccx(0, 1, 2)
            circuit.cx(0,1)
            circuit.measure(1, 0)
            circuit.barrier()
            circuit.reset([0,1])
            circuit.barrier()
        else:
            circuit.ccx(0, 1, j + 2)
            circuit.cx(0,1)
            circuit.ccx(1, j + 1, j + 2)
            circuit.cx(j + 1, 1)
            circuit.measure(1, j)
            circuit.barrier()
            circuit.reset([0,1])
            circuit.barrier()
        j += 1
    circuit.measure(QubitCount - 1, CircuitLenght)
    return circuit
```

It makes 10 + 5 right now.

The code first takes the binary equivalent of the two numbers entered. Then it adds 0 to the byte of the other number, whichever number has more bits. For example:

First Number:
**5 -> 101**

**10 -> 1010**

And then adding zero:

**5 -> 0101**

**10 -> 1010**

and then it does write first byte to q0 and second one to q1. After each adder section it resets qubits and writes next bit. (q0, q1)

So if we wanna add 8-bit numbers then we need 2 input qubits and Carry Qubit as much as bit count. When we do this we just need 10 Qubits for 8-Bit adder.

After this whole things my question is Did I do a good job as a beginner? Is there a anything wrong?

If you wish check out the whole code: https://github.com/Joseph-549/QuantumAdder/blob/main/FunctionLessQubit.ipynb

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.